# android getting data from UIThread

Tags: android

I'm trying to send android data to arduino using `Bluetooth`.My gui contains a `SeekBar` and accelerometer readings.All the `Sockets` are successfully formed and every thing is working fine if I write data to the `OutputStream` of the `Socket` from `onSeekBarChanged()` method so that data will be transferred to arduino whenever I change the SeekBar.

```
 public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        if(seekBar.getId() == R.id.seekBar)
        {
            speed.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            String outputData = String.valueOf(progress)+",";
            try
            {
            streams.write(outputData.getBytes());//writes data to OutputStream of Socket
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("RTR","Sockets not yet formed");
            }

        }
    }
```

The problem is I need to send `Accelerometer` data continuously along with `SeekBar` current value.So I tried to write to `OutputStream` of the `Socket` from `onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)` method of the accelerometer.`Result:Program not responding.`

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        {
            float accXYZ[] = event.values;

            float accX = accXYZ[0];
            float accY = accXYZ[1];
            float accZ = accXYZ[2];

            x.setText(String.format("%.2f",accX));
            y.setText(String.format("%.2f",accY));
            z.setText(String.format("%.2f",accZ));

            String outputData = x.getText().toString()+","+speed.getText().toString()+";";

            try{
                  streams.write(outputData.getBytes());
            }catch (Exception e){
                //Log.d("RTR","X");
            }

        }
    }
```

I understand that this is too much overload on the `UI Thread`.I think I should create a `new Thread` with an infinite loop in `run()` method to send the data continuously.How can I send the accelerometer and SeekBar data to this new Thread continuously.

Or should I collect UIThread's accelerometer and SeekBar's data from this new thread.

```
In Short, how do I get data from UIThread to this new Thread.
```

Please provide all possible solutions you're aware of for my problem and any complications with my current procedure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A nice way to do this is to use the built in [`Looper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) class. Looper is the message queuing system that powers Android's UI thread, and you can use it with your own threads as well. What's nice about the way it's designed is that it creates very little garbage collection load (depending on what argument types you use, it can be none).

I'm writing this freehand, so you'll have to hack at it a bit to make it work, but here's what it could end up looking like:

```
class LooperThread extends Thread {
    private static final int MSG_TYPE_OUTPUT_DATA = 0;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private volatile OutputStream mOutputStream;

    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();

        mHandler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                if (msg.what == MSG_TYPE_OUTPUT_DATA
                    && mOutputStream != null) {
                    //try-catch left out for brevity
                    mOutputStream.write(msg.obj.getBytes());
                }
            }
        };

        Looper.loop();
    }

    public void submitReading(String outputData) {
        mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(MSG_TYPE_OUTPUT_DATA, outputData);
    }
}
```

Your setup code will do something like this:

```
private void setup() {
    Socket sock = setupBluetoothConnection();
    this.looperThread = new LooperThread();
    this.looperThread.setOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
    this.looperThread.start();
}
```

Finally, your sensor event handler:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
    {
        // snip...
        String outputData = x.getText().toString()+","+speed.getText().toString()+";";

        this.looperThread.submitReading(outputData);
    }
}
```

What this gives you is a single background thread that processes messages as fast as it can, and that you can submit messages to in a thread-safe manner from any other thread. They're processed in order.

You'll need to take care to properly shut down the looper thread when you're done, and make sure it can handle the socket connection getting lost.

If you need to throttle it to a certain rate of messages per second, things get a little more complicated. OutputStream.write is a blocking operation, so I've left that out for convenience. What you'd do is register the `System.nanoTime()` that you last processed a message in an instance field, and inside the handleMessage() method, whenever the next message comes in before enough time has passed, you calculate how long you have to wait before you can process the message. This is much easier than handling it at the "submit" side using sendMessageDelayed().

Comment: Indeed it is.Looper is the best possible solution.Though I would suggest using HandlerThread to avoid null handler problems.Thankyou verymuch